# How can I decouple this directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is a really bad piece of code that I wrote for a quick solution at the time.
Basically I want to extend the `<textarea>` with a "N characters left" thingy. So I figured this would be awesome for a neat little directive.

```
<limitedtext model="study.msg" 
             maxlen="400" 
             placeholder="enter email message">
</limitedtext>
```

Here's the template (and things getting ugly):
https://github.com/martinchristov/crg.studyalerts/blob/master/app/partials/limitedtext.html

As you'll notice, I'm using `<textarea ng-model="$parent.study.msg">` which I know is terrible, but that's the whole reason for me posting a question here.

My question is, how can I pass a model to the directive, which can then be updated within the directive, and those updates to be accessible from the directive's parent?
In the case above, I want the directive to update study.msg

Comment: Statt with combining your directive with the `ngModel` directive, use the `require` directive configuration property to get a reference to the `ngModelController` instance and use its API to set and get the value from your `study.msg` scope value.

Comment: You could also look at writing a directive that just 'wraps' other elements and just modifies the dom by injecting the element that does the counting?

Comment: @link64 thanks. that would be one way to do it :)

@lib3d I don't seem to find info on that `require` config property. Can u send me something for reference? thanks!

Comment: @link64 they way you suggested ends up with the same problem. The directive has to know about the parent parent property. In this case `study.msg`.

Comment: About working with the `ngModelController`, please read this: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Comment: If you use transclude, the objects on the parent scope are available in the directive without having to reference the parent.
"The transclude option changes the way scopes are nested. It makes it so that the contents of a transcluded directive have whatever scope is outside the directive, rather than whatever scope is on the inside. In doing so, it gives the contents access to the outside scope."

Comment: Thanks @link64! I was able to make it! :)

Comment: Post your solution and mark it as answered so that others can find this post useful without having to go through all the comments! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, as suggested by @link64 is the following:

```
<limitedtext ng-model="study.msg" maxlen="400" placeholder="enter email message" ng-show="study.via==0"></limitedtext>
```

Directive partial:

```
<div class="limitedtext">
<textarea maxlength="{{maxlen}}" placeholder="{{placeholder}}"></textarea>
<div class="counter" ng-hide="maxlength==0" ng-class="{red:charsleft<0}">{{charsleft}} chars left</div>
</div>
```

Directive JS:

```
directive('limitedtext', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace:true,
    transclude:true,
    require:'?ngModel',
    templateUrl:'partials/limitedtext.html',
    scope:{
        maxlen:'@',
        placeholder:'@'
    },
    link: function ($scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
        var textarea = el.find('textarea');
        ngModel.$render = function(){
            textarea.val(ngModel.$viewValue);
            $scope.charsleft = $scope.maxlen - ngModel.$viewValue.length;
        };
        textarea.on('blur keyup change', function(){
            $scope.$apply(read);
        });
        function read () {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(textarea.val());
            $scope.charsleft = $scope.maxlen - ngModel.$viewValue.length;
        }
    }
};
}]);
```

Thanks!